# Adding a property using Jackson MixIn's?

Tags: jackson, mixins

I know we can use Jackson MixIn's to rename a property or to ignore a property (see examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)).  But is it possible to add a property?

The added property can be:

1. A constant (such as a version number)
2. A computed value (e.g. if the source class has properties for `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, but we want to ignore both and export a `getArea()` instead)
3. Flattened information from nested members (e.g. a class has a member `Information` which in turn has a member `Description`, and we want to have a new property for `description` and skipping the nesting structure of `Information`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations):

> "Mix-in" annotations are a way to associate annotations with classes,
>   without modifying (target) classes themselves, originally intended to
>   help support 3rd party datatypes where user can not modify sources to
>   add annotations.
>
> With mix-ins you can:
>    1. Define that annotations of a '''mix-in class''' (or interface)
>    2. will be used with a '''target class''' (or interface) such that it
>       appears
>    3. as if the ''target class'' had all annotations that the ''mix-in''
>       class has (for purposes of configuring serialization /
>       deserialization)

To solve your problems you can:

- Create new `POJO` which has all required fields.
- Implement custom serialiser.
- Before serialisation convert `POJO` to `Map` and add/remove nodes.
- Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier` to extend custom serialisers. See: [Jackson custom serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249054/jackson-custom-serialization-and-deserialization).

For example, to add a constant version to each object you can wrap it in `Verisoned` class:

```
class Versioned {

    private final String version;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private final Object pojo;

    public Versioned(String version, Object pojo) {
        this.version = version;
        this.pojo = pojo;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public Object getPojo() {
        return pojo;
    }
}
```

Now, if you wrap an `Arae(width, height)` object:

```
Area area = new Area(11, 12);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Versioned("1.1", area));
```

output will be:

```
{
  "version" : "1.1",
  "width" : 11,
  "height" : 12
}
```